# How to use parameters from a json file in pom file?

Tags: java, json, maven, pom.xml

The following answer suggests using org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin for reading from a .properties file.

[how to access variable in pom.xml from external properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107575/how-to-access-variable-in-pom-xml-from-external-properties-file)

Is there a way to do it with a json file?

Thanks

Comment: Did you found any answers yet?